# Can't escape this complex command correctly so it will run properly from the registry

Tags: command-line, powershell, windows-registry, context-menu, console

I am creating a new right click context menu entry for all files. It's located here:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\FileUtilities\shell\a_addtofolder
```

It basically just adds selected files to a new folder. I know the function is rudimentary but this is a learning experience.

The script uses Powershell, singleinstance.exe (https://github.com/zenden2k/context-menu-launcher), and run-hidden.exe (https://github.com/stax76/run-hidden), so it's gonna be a long command. :)

Right now, this command works:

```
"C:\Tools\scripts\singleinstance.exe" "%1" "powershell.exe" -file "C:\Tools\scripts\AddSelectionToFolderSI.ps1" $files --si-timeout 250
```

This is what I need, but it doesn't work:

```
"C:\Tools\scripts\PATH\run-hidden.exe" "C:\Tools\scripts\singleinstance.exe" "%1" "powershell.exe" -file "C:\Tools\scripts\AddSelectionToFolderSI.ps1" $files --si-timeout 250
```

Logically this is what I want to happen:

**run-hidden.exe** > **singleinstance.exe** "%1" > **powershell.exe** -file "C:\Tools\scripts\AddSelectionToFolderSI.ps1" $files > --si-timeout 250

--si-timeout 250 is an argument associated with singleinstance.exe. It's a short timer to allow multiple files to be passed to PowerShell (kind of like if the script was called from the SendTo menu)

I have tried so many different combinations of single and double quotes and I'm just lost.

If anyone can please help, it would be a godsend.

Thanks so much.

Comment: So when you run the non-working command line what is the output? Please [edit] your question and add this information.

Comment: Try putting the `run-hidden.exe` call inside the `singleinstance.exe` call. Perhaps like this: `C:\Tools\scripts\singleinstance.exe "%1" "C:\Tools\scripts\PATH\run-hidden.exe" powershell.exe -file C:\Tools\scripts\AddSelectionToFolderSI.ps1 $files --si-timeout 250`.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks so much! That was it.

Comment: Excellent. So I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to put the `run-hidden.exe` call inside the
`singleinstance.exe` call, like this:

```
C:\Tools\scripts\singleinstance.exe "%1" "C:\Tools\scripts\PATH\run-hidden.exe" powershell.exe -file C:\Tools\scripts\AddSelectionToFolderSI.ps1 $files --si-timeout 250
```